# Deletion of my answer to the question "Why do people believe that if Putin ceases to be Russian president, the Russo-Ukraine war will cease?"

Tags: discussion, answers, deleted-answers

My answer to the question "[Why do people believe that if Putin ceases to be Russian president, the Russo-Ukraine war will cease?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/79989/41763)" was deleted by moderator with this explanation:

> This is not an answer to the question "Why do people believe that if
> Putin ceases to be Russian president, the Russo-Ukraine war will
> cease?". A question "Why do people think something" can not be
> answered with "They should not think that because it is wrong". That
> is missing the subject.

But this was absolutly not what my answer was about. My answer was refering to historical experience. Posibly the moderator was refering to [this answer](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/79990/41763), which I tried to improve, but failed to do that?

The point of my answer was, that the believe that if Putin ceases to be Russian president, the Russo-Ukraine war will cease is based on historical experience. I have shown which exactly historical event this believe is based on. So I don´t see why this is not answering the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are correct. I should not have deleted it for not answering the question. I removed a lot of off-topic answers from that question and yours got a copy&pasted text I should have put more effort into to make it more applicable.

Only the first half of your answer was off-topic. But for a different reason: propaganda lies. Basically everyone in "the west" wants this war to stop. But because Russia doesn't seem to be interested in stopping the illegal conquest of a neighboring country they started, the only way for the war to stop appears to be to support the Ukrainian defense until the Russian military runs out of the resources they need to continue. Which could certainly be called a "defeat". Through their continuing support of Ukraine, NATO leaves Russia two choices: Abandon their war of conquest or bleed out trying.

I removed the propaganda part and undeleted the answer. I still believe that the rest of the answer is incorrect. But as moderators we are not the judges of correctness.

Comment: As mentioned bfor the first part was for clarification which version of ending the war we are talking about. But since it was misinterpreted as propaganda, then removing it was the right solution.

Comment: You deleted text due to "propaganda lies"? How is that neutral?